# If Rachel helped Samara, then why is Samara still killing people?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-ring

In the movie "The Ring" (2002), why does Aidan say that Rachel wasn't supposed to help Samara? And if Rachel had helped Samara, then why is she still killing people? And why does making a copy of the tape and showing it to someone else, free the person from the curse?

Comment: Thing about the English remake of The Ring is... it takes all the mystique of the Japanese original... & tosses it straight out the window. The original doesn't make you ask 'why?' just makes sure you never watch a home video ever again ;)

Comment: I haven't seen the original one. Only the American version

Comment: US remakes always do that, try to over-explain things.  However, the remake of the Ring held its own on eeriness, I think.  It was just a completely different type of movie. And this is coming from a HUGE fan of Japanese horror films.  Kairo (Pulse) (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286751/) is my favorite horror film of all time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall that Samara is murdered by her adoptive mother because the girl had a malignant spirit. Remember the scene of the horses in the cursed video? It is explained that the horses threw themselves off the cliff because Samara frightened them or forced them to do it. In itself, the girl's body was only a vessel for the evil spirit and to die she did nothing but free herself. Rachel buries her corpse so she can rest but her soul is not good and now she can spread the world.
If we go to the book (which doesn't look like the movie but can serve) Sadako has a very powerful mind that transcends time and can materialize but his soul is corrupted and only seeks evil.

In short, Samara was never good or a normal girl. Think about the last movie (very bad, by the way) where they explain the origin of Samara and who were hes parents.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to all of these questions is that Samara is kind of a jerk.  Admittedly, with reason!

Aiden says Rachel isn't supposed to help Samara, because while Rachel thinks helping her will put her to rest, Aiden knows that Samara is a truly malevolent spirit, who isn't interested in being put to rest. She just wants more chaos.

I'm not sure the technical reason (haha) why making a copy of the tape would free the person from the curse, but Samara's reason was that by doing so, more people would learn of her plight.

And just because they won't die in a week doesn't mean they won't be haunted for the rest of their lives.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring back this old thread, but I have a more  logical answer to why she keeps killing. She was mistreated as we learned in the movie, so Rachel helped her as we also learned. At the end of the movie we pan into the copy of the video cassette and I imagine some people confused at this point.

The reason they panned in to the cassette is because she had just realized that because she made the cassette, the girl was happy with her. The only way you escape death and watch the cassette is by making a copy. Samara wants her story to be told, so when Rachel made the copy, she was happy.

At the end of the movie, it showed Rachel and her son watching it and making a copy, and her telling her son it's going to be okay. Samara keeps killing if the person that watches the tape doesn't make a copy. She wants her story to be told.

I hope I helped shine some light on the question, and wish you happy scary movies!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I think that Aiden told Rachel not to help Samara because she was never meant to; those who watch can only try to survive the seven days. Though Rachel thought helping Samara would put her spirit at rest, she actually just ended up spreading the curse to Noah. Why? Because Samara was never 'normal'. In her video, she says she 'can't stop' hurting people and it's referenced a few times that she 'never sleeps', implying she was born a malevolent being- pure evil. Therefore she never sought help, retribution or for anyone to find out her true story. When Rachel grasps the copy of the tape, she realises that the reason she and Aiden are spared is because she passed the curse on, which is the only way of escaping it. In my perspective, Rachel was never freed for helping or sympathising but was rather just another tool used to spread Samara's mayhem.

Answer (score 0):

No guys, the reason she didn't die was because she made Noah watch the tape, at that time she didn't know that was the way to survive. And her mother killed her because Samara made everything worse for her parents, and her ‘’ fake’’ mother who tried so bad to get a child which she couldn't, could not live with the pain of killing Samara, so she jumped after she killed her.

Answer (score 0):

Other than she wanted to do more harm, she wanted a do-over, that's why she possessed Aiden's body and was calling Rachel mommy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I believe it could be a possibility that Samara chose not to take Rachel was the fact she was also taking the two closest people in her life already. From Rachel knowing so deeply about the girl and who she is, her taking Noah and Aidan brings forth an eternal agony from Samara. It’s the ultimate agony she could put someone through aside from just killing them. This is something that will sit with Rachel for the rest of her life, and she knows exactly who is behind it. Unlike the families of anyone else she has killed.